# Access div element from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a div element which I would like to change it'e dir attribute from the code.
The problem is that I can't set the `runat=server` attribute on the div, so it's not accessible from the code.

Using asp.net, c#, framework 4.0.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say that you can't set runat="server"? As I remember WebForms it's possible (you'll get untyped HtmlControl object).

Comment: I have a grid unger this div, and I loop on this grid, and changing things on the grid. if this div is set to runat=server, then this loop get messed up. Don't know why..

Comment: @Itay.B: Then I suggest you start a separate question to find out why runat=server on the div messes up your loop on the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to set the div to `runat="server"` so you can do the following:

```
<div dir='<%= GetDir() %>'>
    Your text
</div>
```

and in the code behind you can set the direction using the following code:

```
if(You Condition)
        {
            return "ltr";
        }
        else
        {
            return "rtl";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't access to the client elements on the page, only to the server-ones (asp.net is a server-oriented framework). The client controls are compiled to the [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) controls with html in them.

If you don't want to set `div` for the `runat="server"` attribute, you can [register client script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) to edit your divs content.
If you set the `runat="server"` attribute, and set the `ID="YOUR_DIV_ID_HERE"` for it, it will be accessible from code under `YOUR_DIV_ID_HERE` name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can do this also

```
<div><%= your server variable %> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery and call back function to call server side function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the runat="server" attribute on a HTML element. Just did a local demo, works just fine. It will be represented as an HtmlGenericControl (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=VS.100).aspx).

EDIT: You say you cannot use runat="server" to access the element from code. I am not sure why that would be a problem, as the html rendering should be no different. Maybe it has to do with the elements client side id beeing changed? If you depend on this, you could try setting ClientIdMode=Static for your div.